# React Hook Form useFieldArray overwriting my own id

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

In my schema, I have an id property. When I use `useFieldArray`, it automatically overrides that id.

I'm using shadcn-ui

react-hook-form: 7.45.0

```
const { fields, append, remove, update } = useFieldArray<{ id?: string, test?: number[] }>({
    name: 'testArray',
    control: form.control,
  });
```

```
fields.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={item.id}>
    <FormField
       name={`testArray.${index}.id`}
       render={({ field }) => (
         <FormItem>
           <Select
             onValueChange={field.onChange}
             defaultValue={field.value}
           > 
             <FormControl>
               <SelectTrigger>
                 <SelectValue placeholder="Select" />
               </SelectTrigger>
             </FormControl>
             <SelectContent>
               {
                 selects?.map((select) => (
                   <SelectItem value={select.id}>{select.name}</SelectItem>
                 ))
               }
             </SelectContent>
           </Select>
         </FormItem>
       )}
     />
     {
     item.test.map((value: number, index2: number) => (
       <div>
         <FormField
           key={`${value}`}
           name={`testArray.${index}.test.${index2}`}
           render={({ field: testField }) => (
             <FormItem className="w-full">
               <FormControl>
                 <Slider onValueChange={(currentValue) => form.setValue(`testArray.${index}.test.${index2}`, currentValue[0])} value={[testField .value]} />
               </FormControl>
             </FormItem>
           )}
         />
       </div>
     ))
   }
   <Button onClick={() => update(index, { id: item.id, split: [...item.test, 0] })}>Add Number To Array</Button>
   <Button onClick={() => remove(index)}>Remove</Button>
</div>

<Button
  onClick={() => append({
    id: '',
    test: [100],
  })}
>
  Add List
</Button>
```

I've read that I could use keyName property which works fine, but docs says that its deprecated and id shouldn't be overridden in newer version, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same. This library requires a 'unique' id prop to be able to add new entries. However, you can specify that `keyName` to be different. As you experienced, the default `keyName` is `id`. See example below:

```js
// myItemsThatHaveId is of type { id: number; something: string; }[] in the state

const { fields, update } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'myItemsThatHaveId',
    keyName: '_id'
  });

// field will now have id: number; _id: string; something: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

i hade the same issue and you can fix it by changing default `keyName`,
`keyName` by default is set on `id` thast why it overwrite the `id` field.
you should change it to some other name :

```
const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    keyName: 'uid', //  Add any name to chang keyName
    name: 'test',
});
```